# What kind of Aquarium background is better? SelfAdhesive or with Glue?

Tags: aquarium, safety

I have aquarium 32" x 16", it is brand new and I am looking for some aquarium background. I am now deciding between using SelfAdhesive or Normal one? Any Advices?

Answer (score 3):

I use tape along the edges. Using Glue and self adhesive is harder to get off if 1) you put it on crooked and need to re-arrange and 2)  Want to ever change the background completely.

Glue and self adhesion can leave sticky residue thats hard to clean off.

Downside, unless you find a very clear tape, or can hide it well, too much tape can look tacky.

Answer (score 2):

What I found when I was looking for a great background for my 20gal.tank, was live plants. Some of them, such as Water Sprite are very easy to grow and spread very quickly.

They may also grow above water level (depending how tall your aquarium is) and float along the top of your aquarium, unless you decide to trim off the tops and stick those back into the substrate, thereby creating more plants.

There are many others that are easy to grow plants that are great for backgrounds and the fish love them for hiding places, my fish also love scrounging for leftover food on them. You can go on YouTube to "Beginner Aquarium Plants" and it will pull up many videos about this subject.